# DAX Power BI select only max date rows of each month

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax, powerquery

i've a table (left one), i want to apply a dax formula to keep only IDs of the last date of a month. (if a date is the last for the month, i keep all its rows)

My ouput will be the right table.
I've many columns of course, i just displayed two for the POC.

[image]

in sql it's like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table t1
WHERE t1.date = (select max(t2.date) 
             from table t2
             where month(t1.date)= month(t2.date)
             and year(t1.date) = year(t2.date)
             )
```

I tried many formulas and solutions usiing `Summarize`and `Evaluate` but none worked for me.
I want to make the filter in Edit Query after each Data Refresh.